What order of precedence should we try to retrieve an environment variable?
When we retrieve an environment variable (for example, a connection string), this variable can be stored in one or more targets - process, machine or user as shown here: EnvironmentVariableTarget Fields
What order of precedence is considered "good practice" in trying to retrieve said value?

You shouldn't be looking at anything but the process's environment variables. The machine- and user-configured environnemt variables are not the actual environment variables. A process can be started without inheriting its parent process's environment variables, and when that happens, it's not supposed to know the machine- and user-configured values. The enum you mentioned is only for writing the configuration, not reading run-time values. Only the process's run-time values matter when reading something like, in your example, a connection string.

@madreflection how do we go about setting a process's environment variables without showing the secrets in the code? This would be an issue when pushing to a public repository

What do you mean by "without showing the secrets in the code" ?

@TP95.  You don't commit secrets to a public repo.  Period.  There are reasons you might use SetEnvironmentVariable.  One is to set an environment variable before forking a child process.  Most environment variables have nothing to do with secrets (of course, some do hold secrets).

@madreflection "The enum you mentioned is only for writing the configuration, not reading run-time values."  That is not correct.  The documentation gives Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envVar, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) as an example.  If you mean you normally shouldn't do this, I agree.

@MatthewFlaschen: Let me rephrase. The enum is for reading and writing configuration, not reading run-time values. You're not supposed to read the machine- or user-level configuration to get environment variables. That defeats the purpose of creating, for example, a process that doesn't inherit the environment variables of the parent process.

@madreflection An example: SetEnvironmentVariable ("DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING", "Blablabla connection string used for connecting to an SQL server"). Yes, a connection string isn't really critical like a password, but its still not desirable to show this line in a public git repository.

You should not be using SetEnvironmentVariable for that purpose. The environment variable should be set by, for example, IIS, where you've configured that environment variable on the application, and that value is stored (relatively protected by the file system) in applicationhost.config. IIS includes it in the environment variables when it creates the process for the web application. Similar techniques can be used for Windows Services.

@madreflection But this is just moving the responsibility to the IIS and it ties us to the Microsoft hosting  and Windows world. What if we want our application to be not dependent on what its being hosted on, like for example putting it on AWS or Vercel?

It doesn't have to be IIS. It could be a docker image, or something else. The point is that the application itself is not responsible for setting the values because it can't be. The operating environment itself has to take responsibility for that. All your application needs to know and expect is that it was created with that environment variable in its environment block and that it can use it.

@TP95 There are a lot of secure secret stores available (this is off-topic for your question, but Chef Vault and Docker Secrets are a couple examples).  The key points relevant to your question are: 1. Use GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName). 2. Sometimes that requires a restart to get the latest.  If it still doesn't work, it's a ServerFault question.  Something is strange with your server/hosting environment.

@MatthewFlaschen Thanks for the suggestions. I also saw Secret Manager for the windows world without relying on a third party.

@madreflection Makes sense. It still may not hurt to keep a safety check like "in the unlikely chance the variable is not found in process, look in the user. If its not in the user, look in the machine".

No. Don't do that. If it's not in the process, terminate with an appropriate message. That's your safety check, validating your configuration. In the unlikely event that it's not in the process, you did something wrong when configuring your operating environment and you need to fix that. Don't hide the fact that you did something wrong. You could pick up the wrong value without knowing it and really cause yourself problems.

@madreflection if it is "wrong" to pick up the variable from the user or machine, why is it offered as an option in the first place? Why would these enums ever be used if, by your logic, they are so problematic?

Unified API.  I would say that it's nothing more than that. Process vs. the other two, they do entirely different things and for entirely different purposes. And the more I think about it, the more I think it was a poor design choice. The Win32 API has entirely different functions for dealing with process vs. configuration.

@TP95 Don't assume that every feature is for your use case.  For example, C# has an unsafe mode that allows you to use C-like features like raw pointers.  Unless you're writing very specific types of code, it's not for you (or me).  Don't assume you should be using GetEnvironmentVariable with non-Process targets either.  It's the answer to someone's question, but not this one.

@TPS: Speaking of the answer to someone's question, Matthew Flaschen did a better job of answering your question and the real issue at hand, and that deserves to be the acepted answer. The other answer talks about different configuration sources, which is the answer to a very different question.

Secret Manager is not a secure secret store ("The Secret Manager tool doesn't encrypt the stored secrets and shouldn't be treated as a trusted store.").  It's for development only, though it may help you avoid accidentally checking in secrets.  A Microsoft cloud secure secret store is Azure Key Vault.

There's multiple approaches and my preference is to use two, for my settings I use this order:

Code Properties hardcoded
App Settings config file
EnvVars

Where App Settings override hardcoded properties so users can customize and EnvVars override all as they tend to be confidential settings.

However with my EnvVars I use the principle of least impact first and greatest impact last. This approach ensures that more specific, configurations (like those for the current process) take precedence over more global, persistent ones (like those for the machine).
For example a user may temporarily create a DBConnString (User) EnvVar and expect that to take precedence for their testing.

Thank you. I had to skip the hardcoded code properties or app settings (launchsettings too) config files as I did not want to accidently push secrets into the git repo. As for the environment variables, I had a similar thought intuitively too (process -> user -> machine)

"with my EnvVars I use the principle of least impact first and greatest impact last" implies that you need to set up this ordering manually, which is not correct.  It's how the environment variable system automatically works (unless special retrieval methods are used).

Normally, you should simply use GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName), which is equivalent to GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process).
You don't need to do multiple hierarchical retrievals yourself (normally).
There are conventions (explained below) for how the environment variable data flows, which your program should normally follow (so it does not surprise users).  Calling only the above method helps your program follow these conventions.

More details:
The above call retrieves the value from the current process's environment block.
Per the documentation, the contents of this environment block are initially inherited from the parent process.
Only if there is no parent process, "per-machine and per-user environment variables are used instead. For example, a new console window has all per-machine and per-user environment variables defined at the time it was launched."
This block also includes "Any variables added to the process block while the process is running by calling either the SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String) method or the SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget) method with a target value of EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process."  This means you can update your program's environment variables live.
Finally, note that ".NET on Unix-like systems does not support per-machine or per-user environment variables."

There is a good advantage to environment variables in the process, but in my use case simply using GetEnvironmentVariable("foo") or GetEnvironmentVariable("foo", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) returned an empty value because I had stored it in my dev machine's windows user variable for security reasons. Which is why I was building hierarchical retrievals and seeing opinions about the precedence of the targets.

If you configured an environment variable at the user level and you're not seeing the value from your process, you need to log out and back in (or reboot) so that the variable is configured at the root process and inherited by all processes started form it, like the shell, then Visual Studio, and so on.

@madreflection this is what I was experiencing too. The variable is not stored in the process target when we have it in a user / machine level. And this is not uncommon, I believe most hosting platforms actually provide environment variable config at the machine level.

Technically, the machine/user env vars have nothing to do with absence of parent process relationships. The only process that doesn't have a parent is the session manager. The machine environment variables are configuration that the session manager uses to configure itself, whilst the user env vars are configuration used by Winlogon. After Winlogon sets up the process block for the users shell, they are never looked at again.

It's best not to think of the machine/user env vars as env vars themselves, but the system configuration for what the env vars are initially set to.
